# Sum every N col and row in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a data list more than 100 row in csv file sth like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 9 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 |

I need to sum each 5 cell of a column
And write the answer in a new row sth like this will be:
Note: its just for the first three column and N = 5:

| J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18 | 0 |
| 0 | 18 | 0 |

The code that i use is below  but I dont now how to sum every 5 cells of a column and write the output in a new column :

```py
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df[df.columns[4:]].sum()
```

Comment: You need to be more specific here: _"And write the answer in a new row"_. Do you want to insert new rows into the _existing_ dataframe with the sums for every 5 rows or do you want to build a new dataframe. Also, why are the column names `J`, `K`, `L` here and not `A`, `B`, `C`? Please add the **complete** expected output for the provided sample to your question.

Comment: The output of sum is in new columns..ex: sum 5 cells of column A is equal by zero and I write the value in colum J ..next sum of 5 cells of column B is equal by 18 and I write the value in K and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to do that:

```
N = 5
df_sum = df.groupby([n // N for n in range(df.shape[0])]).sum()
```

The list used to group over uses floor division to build blocks of 5 consecutive rows. If you're using the standard index you could do

```py
df_sum = df.groupby(df.index // N).sum()
```

instead.

Result for your sample:

```
   A   B  C  D  E   F  H
0  0  18  0  9  0  45  0
1  0  18  0  9  0  45  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ..but if I want to sum each row and put the result of 7 consecutive rows after column H ...can I used groupby too?

Comment: @FatoomThk I'm not sure I understand completely: Do you want to sum over the columns, i.e. sum up each row? If that's the case then you could do `df["sum"] = df.sum(axis=1)`. That puts the result into a new column, after `H`.